# Edit text in-line in an Adobe Acrobat Document .pdf?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I've been asked to make changes to a .pdf file.  This consists of removing a single line of text.

I have been given this .pdf file, but the original file that the .pdf file was generated from has been lost.  Is there some way to do this with or without Adobe Acrobat Pro?

**Edit**:  I know that in general, editing .pdf files is not practical; I want to emphasize that I want to edit text inline.  I do not want to change anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the whiteout feature of the [PDFescape](http://www.pdfescape.com/) online PDF editor.

Depending on your operating system you may be able to use [PDFedit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/).

The expensive way of doing it is, yes, with Acrobat Pro's Touch-Up text tool. But I prefer open source whenever possible.

Converting back to HTML or Word format, etc., is probably going to end up changing a lot more than you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

If the file isn't password protected or set to be not editable you may be able to edit it via Adobe Acrobat Pro.  That would probably be the easiest way to do it.

If you can't get your hands on Adobe Acrobat or can't open the file for editing there are other ways you could edit the file.

(1) I have used services online before which allow you to give them a PDF and they will email you a word file with the contents of the pdf:
http://www.google.com/search?q=pdf+to+word

(2) Take a screenshot and edit that, save it back as a PDF containing an image.